# apache2 --version shows error, -v does not

Tags: lubuntu, apache2, php

```
owner@G700:/var/www/wptest1$ apache2 --version
[Fri Mar 15 01:29:11.505305 2019] [core:warn] [pid 4929]
 AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid 
directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

owner@G700:/var/www/wptest1$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-10-10T18:59:25
```

I'm on Lubuntu 18.04. I have removed/purged and installed, and restarted apache2 about 10 times trying to fix this (as it may relate to php not working / php files showing raw code in browser).

Comment: Perhaps your faulty config files for apache survived uninstall? Can you post the offending line in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` ? Try running `vim +80 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and it should open the offending config line ...

Comment: Is your config file line looking like `DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}` ?

Comment: You should verify that your `/etc/apache2/envvars` file contains the line `export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX` .

Comment: Yes, line 80 shows: `DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}`. As to your 2nd comment this is line 20: `export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX`

Comment: The problem is the rather awkward fact that calling `apache2` binary directly doesn't set nor export environment variables from `/etc/apache2/envvars`. I don't now which versions it started to be obligatory to start `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` or `service apache2 start`, but now it is a must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main error is:

```
AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
```

You should try to run apache via the `/etc/init.d/apache2` start/stop script, not the binary directly. The script should export all environment variables needed, from `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Try:

```
# service apache2 restart
```

See the explanation here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/558283/apache2-config-variable-is-not-defined

I can reproduce your error:

```
root@efk:~# service apache2 stop
root@efk:~# /usr/sbin/apache2 --version
[Thu Mar 14 20:54:17.111349 2019] [core:warn] [pid 28733]
AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to
ServerRoot
root@efk:~# service apache2 start
root@efk:~# apachectl --status
httpd (pid 28782) already running
root@efk:~# service apache2 stop
root@efk:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
[ ok ] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
root@efk:~# apachectl --status
httpd (pid 28966) already running
```

So, it is evident that the `apache2` must be called through init script and not by directly calling the binary. Now by calling init script I can confirm that it works either way, `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` or `service apache2 start`. Both start the daemon via the `systemctl` command.